# Current user's locale in ProcessBuilder

Tags: process-builder, locale, system-fields, languagelocalekey

I am trying to access the Locale field of the running user in Process Builder. The field is not available from the field list. I have also tried to access the field in the following ways:

$User.LocaleSidKey
$User.LanguageLocaleKey

But, I get the error message that the field doesn't exist.

Any idea how can I access the locale?
Thanks!